# Configuring Wireless Networking in 11.04

Tags: 11.04, wireless

How do I setup wireless connection in my Ubuntu 11.04?
How to configure the connection? How to get the details like SSID and all that...

Comment: Generally speaking, there is no need to configure or setup wireless networking, because the pre-installed Network Manager does the job for you. Obviously, you need to setup a wireless router, but that's unrelated to Ubuntu. Your question is too laconic. Perhaps you can explain what happens when you try connecting to a wireless network. In case there are error messages, post them. In case there aren't any networks to connect to, specify that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using network manager, right click the "Network Manager" icon, hit "Connection Information".  It will show you all those details.

And if I remember correctly, the SSID is the network name (so if the wifi network's name is "IAmTheEvil", then the SSID is "IAmTheEvil").

However, if you are trying to configure your wireless networking, Network Manager is basically "click and connect", just left-click the Network Manager icon, and then choose the wifi network to connect to.  If you don't know the SSID of your wifi, you're kind of out of luck there.

Answer (score 0):

> Over recent years it has become increasingly common for computers to
>   be connected to local area networks and the Internet via wireless
>   Wi-Fi connections. This has spread from the home and public spaces
>   such as libraries and Cafes into the enterprise, especially with the
>   advent of increased wireless security and faster standards such as
>   802.11n.
>
> Support for wireless networking in Ubuntu has come a long way since
>   the days of manually editing network configuration files. In fact,
>   configuring access to Wi-Fi networks using Ubuntu is now easier than
>   it has ever been thanks to something called the Network Manager.

If you're looking for a tutorial that guides you through the process, then [take a look at this](http://www.divms.uiowa.edu/help/wireless/ubuntu1104.html).

Source: http://techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_Ubuntu_11.04_Wireless_Networking